# Measuring voltage from home to outbuilding

Tags: electrical

I want to make sure all the power going from the house to the outbuilding is getting to it. I have installed meters at the point leaving the house and at the point where it is entering the outbuilding.

The voltage is 120V. The wire is 12 gauge double insulated and in metal conduit, buried in ground. The distance traveled is approx 100 ft. I am losing about 3.5 % of what I am sending, using about .85 kilowatts a day.

Is this a normal loss?

Comment: You are not using it in the sense of paying for it.  You are losing it.  Would replace 12 gauge with at least 10 or 8 gauge, so not losing the voltage.  Your electrical tools/lights will like you better.  Do light/s dim if turning on something else?

Comment: I started writing an answer, but there are too many unknowns. The actual voltage drop/power loss is highly dependent on the current and wire size. Pushing 8A all the time is not the same as pushing 12A 2/3 of the time or 16A 1/2 the time. **What is your actual typical usage pattern?**

Comment: @manassehkatz- I would agree the op provided 120v, 3.5% drop and 12 awg wire as .85kw means nothing for real power used as it doesn't correlate to the voltage drop and has no time associated so there are more questions that need to be answered but one answer is you pay for small wires in losses or you pay for more copper and have smaller losses. Similar to what crip659 is stating. VTC.

Comment: What are you trying to run in your outbuilding?

Comment: Could you review  your use of the term "kilowatts" and compare it to the term "kilowatt-hours" and make sure you are using the right term?  How did you arrive at 3.5% and 0.85 kilowatts?

Answer (score 1):

For a 120v circuit to have that loss, Your load is in the 12 amp range this will produce 3.47% voltage drop or 4.167v so you can look at the cost of running a small conductor.

the wire is consuming some of the power.
I am not sure how you came up with your numbers
If your actual voltage drop is 3.5% 120v 100’ 12awg copper this would provide 12 amps, based on 1.9029 resistance per 1k feet 0.054 ohms reactance per 1k feet with a actual Voltage drop of 4.167v as stated above. Southwire.com used.

P= I x E  12a x 120v =1440w  but power is charged in watt hours so your .850 kw or 850w means nothing and is not matching up with a 3.5% voltage drop on a 120v line.

If you would like further assistance figuring out what is really happening we can help there but with the info provided things don’t correlate.

Answer (score 0):

It's a fairly thin wire for such a distance, so you will see a measurable voltage drop at the far end.  How big that drop is depends on the current you draw.

The [RapidTables Calculator](https://www.rapidtables.com/calc/wire/voltage-drop-calculator.html) will give an idea of the expected voltage drop for any given wire size and current.

Comment: The wire is fine for even longer distances but the wire losses then become part of the power consumed calculation.